# Exported sequelize instance is undefined in Model imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, import, sequelize.js

Good evening.

I have an express server. The main script of the server has the following export:

```
export const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  'postgres', config.db_user, config.db_password, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: config.db_port,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  })
```

And I'm trying to create a file structure that allows for each model to be define in a different file. Right now I have a Sequelize model defined like this:

```
import { Test } from "@api-models";
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../main";

Test.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    joinedDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
}, {sequelize: sequelize})

export default Test
```

But this doesn't work, as the `sequelize` import in the model file returns `undefined`, and the initialization fails with the following error message:

`Error: No Sequelize instance passed`

I've been investigating for a while, but most answers seem to rely on node or JS exporting syntax to specify the order of execution, rather than ES6 imports/exports. What would be the proper approach to do this?

Comment: `main` is the file you showed first (the one with the sequelize)?

Comment: That's right! And it's in fact the first thing that the script does, right after the imports.

Comment: I guess in that `main` you have the `const Sequelize = require('sequelize');`, don't you?

Comment: I don't have that exactly because as I mentioned I'm using the ES6 import syntax, so I have the following:

`import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';`

The const `sequelize` has a sequelize instance in the main file, it just dissapears when I try to import it from the model file.

Comment: can you try to console.log the sequelize value you're trying to export. Declare it, console.log it and then export it, maybe it's undefined since initializing

Answer (score 3):

This was solved, what was happening is that there was a circular dependency between the router, the models and the main file which initialized both.

Moving the Sequelize initialization logic to a different file solved the issue.